# Tesseract - invalid literal for int() with base 10: '90.214363'

Tags: python, string, dictionary, tesseract, integral

Why does it recognize the "conf" as if it were a string?
...

'conf': ['-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '90.214363', '-1', '77.749153', '61.677670'],

I'm trying to transform it into a INT but I can't..

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

import pytesseract
import cv2
from pytesseract import Output

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
img = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\Documents\Python\OCR\Programa\teste_manuscrito_01.jpg")
rgb = cv2.cvtColor (img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

resultado = pytesseract.image_to_data(rgb, lang='por', output_type=Output.DICT)

n_boxes = len(resultado['text'])
for i in range(n_boxes):
    if int(resultado['conf'][i]) > 60:
        (x, y, w, h) = (resultado['left'][i], resultado['top'][i], resultado['width'][i], resultado['height'][i])
        img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

Comment: you could try removing the quotation marks from your input if it is supposed to be numerical.

`'conf': [-1, -1, -1, -1, 90.214363, -1, 77.749153, 61.677670]`

also note that casting to int will not do proper rounding. so if it's important that 77.7... becomes 78, you need to round it differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do conversion of float string to int that way. Modify relevant part of your code to this:

```
for i, conf in enumerate(resultado['conf']):
    try:
        int_conf = int(float(conf))       
    except:
        print(f"Can not convert to int: '{conf}'")
        continue
    if int_conf > 60:
        (x, y, w, h) = (resultado['left'][i], resultado['top'][i], resultado['width'][i], resultado['height'][i])
        img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```